# How can I stop EF trying to update a computed column for SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have this object map for Entity Framework:

```
public WordDefinitionMap(string schema)
{
    ToTable(schema + ".WordDefinition");
    HasKey(x => x.WordDefinitionId);

    Property(x => x.WordDefinitionId).HasColumnName(@"WordDefinitionId").IsRequired().HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    Property(x => x.WordFormId).HasColumnName(@"WordFormId").IsRequired().IsUnicode(false).HasColumnType("varchar").HasMaxLength(20);
    Property(x => x.Ascii).HasColumnName(@"Ascii").IsOptional().HasColumnType("int").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);

    // Foreign keys
    HasRequired(a => a.WordForm).WithMany(b => b.WordDefinitions).HasForeignKey(c => c.WordFormId); // FK_WordDefinitionWordForm
}

public class WordDefinition
{
    public int WordDefinitionId { get; set; } // WordDefinitionId (Primary key)
    public string WordFormId { get; set; } // WordFormId (length: 20)
    public int? Ascii { get; set; } // Ascii

    // Foreign keys
    public virtual WordForm WordForm { get; set; } // FK_WordDefinitionWordForm
}
```

When I use Entity Framework to try to update this object I am getting an exception saying:

```
The column "Ascii" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.
```

I thought I was already instructing EF to ignore this property but it would seem it is still trying to update it even though it is null. Is there some way I can change the mapping so **EF does not set** this property?

Comment: Then I you shoud just remove the following configuration `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);` on Ascii configuration

Comment: Isn't that the instruction that tells (or should tell) EF not to touch that column? You're suggesting I remove that and what would I replace it with? Thanks

Comment: Because Accii property is not a primary key. EF will considerate this property as a non-generated property.

Comment: okay but if I just remove it then won't EF just consider it a normal property and try and set it to null?

Comment: Even if the property is not nullable type as long as the property is not a numeric primary key EF will only get the data you set to that property and put it as it is in your database.

Comment: But I don't want to set the column. I want EF to ignore it and not touch it.  I think maybe I was not clear with my question.

Comment: Where are you creating and adding the `WordDefinitionMap`? Are you sure the fluent mapping for EF is ever called inside your application?

Comment: Would decorating the Ascii property with [NotMapped] be what you are looking for?

Comment: @FedericoDipuma - You are correct. Can you include this as an answer. Thanks very much !

Comment: @SamanthaJ but this would mean you do not retrieve this property whenever you query this entity as well.. you should decorate it with `[DatabaseseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`. But your fluent configuration is already doing it, so make put a breakpoint in the `WordDefinitionMap` and make sure it gets hit. And show us that code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception message suggests that your fluent configuration is completely ignored by the framework because there is nothing wrong with you code.

Entity Framework then maps your properties using the standard convention, without knowing that `Ascii` property is a computed one.

To resolve the issue check that an instance of your `WordDefinitionMap` class is created and added to the modelBuilder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WordDefinitionMap("mySchema"));
    //other mappings
}
```

As an aside: I would suggest you to make your computed property not writeable by turning its setter `private`:

```
public int? Ascii { get; private set; } // Ascii
```

This will avoid mistakenly setting this property while EF will continue to populate it from the database without problems.